# Cannot login to local nexus repository with docker

Tags: docker, nexus3

I'm running the nexus repository as a docker container in my local network `[192.168.0.100:8081]`

- Step 1. Create a new docker-hosted repository. In the repository, settings assign a new port in the HTTP field `[8083]`
- Step 2. Create `/etc/docker/daiemon.json` file and add below code:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["http://192.168.0.100:8083"]
}
```

- Step 3. Allow port `[8083]` in firewall

When I try to log in with: `docker login 192.168.0.100:8083`, I'm getting the below error.

```
Error response from daemon: Get "http://192.168.0.110:8083/v2/": dial tcp 192.168.0.100:8083: connect: connection refused
```

Also, I don't see port `[8083]` listening in `netstat -lnpt` return

Any ideas what can be the issue?

Comment: Did you spell this wrong? `daiemon.json`

Comment: It is just misspelling in question.